# How do I prevent an endless loop when deploying a Spring-Boot application to Jetty as a war?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is similar to: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/694 but not the same thing.  I am not using a custom error controller, just a error web page with a thyme template.  I am using Spring Boot 1.1.3.RELEASE and Spring Boot Actuator 1.1.3.RELEASE.

I have a method that produces application/octet-stream.  When an error occurs and I'm running embedded I get a Jetty error page.  When I'm running deployed as a war in Jetty jetty-9.1.4.v20140401 it enters an endless loop.

If I change the produces type to "application/json" it returns an expected json response:

```
{"timestamp":1404326345115,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"java.io.IOException","message":"Cannot run program \"./makenode.sh\" (in directory \"/opt/myapp/rabbitmq\"): error=2, No such file or directory"}
```

If I have it as application/octet-stream I get caught in this loop:

```
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.handleErrorStatus(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:85)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1622)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:549)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:586)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1111)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:478)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1045)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:101)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.handleErrorStatus(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:85)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1622)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:549)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:586)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1111)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:478)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
```

This loop does not happen if I run embedded Jetty.

Comment: There was a problem in Boot 1.1.3 with the embedded servlet container being packaged in the wrong place in an executable jar: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1187. It's worth trying a 1.1.4 snapshot to eliminate that as a cause of your problem.

Comment: Also worth trying with Tomcat (just to get a bead on what might be causing the problem).

Comment: I ended up just switching to an embedded Tomcat instead of a deployed war.  Simplified a lot of things.